# Everything up-to-date but chanches to commited not empty

Tags: git

I spent some time looking for similiar issue on Stackoverflow but did not managed to find one.

I have a local git repo. Very simple, no branch. I used to do the following commands to push stuff into a remote repository:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

This worked for ages and now for "some reason", this no longer working, and I m not able to find why.

If i do a git status I got the following result:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   myproject/node/app.js
        modified:   myproject/node/controllers/admin/admin_controller.js
```

Fine , I have some new stuff to commit. Let's add it to a new commit

```
git add --all
(result is a blank line)
```

Then I commit

```
git commit -m "some message"
 (result is a blank line)
```

And finally I push

```
git push
Unauthorized access is prohibited and monitored!
Everything up-to-date
```

But when I do a git status the file is still to be commited

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   myproject/node/app.js
        modified:   myproject/node/controllers/admin/admin_controller.js
```

I only have one branch locally and one branch remote

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Any idea welcome :)

Comment: Do you have any pre-commit hooks that could be preventing the commit from taking place? https://githooks.com/ (look in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`)

Comment: No only the .sample files in the hooks folder